# UIActivityIndicatorView animation issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uikit, uiactivityindicatorview

I am using a `UIActivityIndicatorView` as an `IBOutlet`. I am trying to control it using `[activityView startAnimating]` and `[activityView stopAnimating]`.

I have enabled 'Hides when stopped' and 'Animating' behaviors in XIB file.

I want to start animate the spinner for several user actions inside the controller. But after the first `[activityView stopAnimating]` call it does not response to `[activityView startAnimating]` call again.

That is mean the spinner is disappeared after the first `[activityView stopAnimating]` call.

I tried `activeView.hidden = NO;` before the next `[activityView startAnimating]` call. But it does not work.

Any idea about this issue?

**Edited**

After my controller loaded I do follow thing,

```
do {

    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    [webServiceCallOperation getResults];

    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

} while (![webServiceCallOperation isValideResponse] || [webServiceCallOperation isServerError]);
```

In the same controller I have a IBAction for a button click.

```
- (IBAction)tappedSearchButton:(id)sender
{    
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    [self tappedSearchButtonAction];

    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}
```

I noticed that the spinner not begin to animate just after the `[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];` call. Using `[self tappedSearchButtonAction];` I call to a web service and go to the search results view. The spinner begin to animate just before change the view. That's why I did not see it. But I suppose to animate it before web service call and should animate it while my web service call.

Same behavior of the network activity indicator.

Comment: Are you sure it is not released? Also, you start the second time on the main thread only, right?

Comment: Provide some code. It's difficult to understand what is going on. Check if the indicator stays under your curent displayed view.

Comment: Sure. I do not release the spinner object. And also I noticed the problem. It's animating. But it does not animating just after the [activityView startAnimating] call. I could not find when it starts to animate. I edited my problem by adding my codes.

Answer (score 0):

As aadhira suggested check for release and if you are making the calls on the main thread.

```
[NSObject performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(SEL) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

It starts animating because as you say you have enabled Animating behavior in the XIB file. But after you stop it for the first time, it is not animating anymore until you start it again programatically.